# gethostbyname xcode issues

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsstring, gethostbyname

Hey guys, I'm new at this stuff, but I'm trying to use gethostname() to work using xcode and the ipad. I've tried a couple of things, but they all seem to freeze up.

So when I just do:

```
host = gethostbyname("website.com");
```

that works fine. I'd like to be able to change the website from within the program though.

I've tried:

```
const char *server = [Website_NSString UTF8String];                    
host = gethostbyname(server);
```

```
const char *server = [Website_NSString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];     
host = gethostbyname(server);
```

```
const char *server[256];        
[Website_NSString getCString:server maxLength:256 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];    
host = gethostbyname(Website_NSString);
```

and

```
host = gethostbyname(Website_NSString);
```

They've either come up with a the warning: Passing argument 1 of 'gethostbyname' from incompatible pointer type, or no warning at all. Still everytime the app just freezes. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. If I do:

```
char server[256];
[Website_NSString getCString:server maxLength:256 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
host = gethostbyname(server);
```

It works fine.