# Programmatically finding IP address of another computer on LAN

Tags: objective-c, ip-address, lan

I want to programmatically obtain the IP address of a computer on the LAN, given its hostname.

I know from the command line i can do this by ping < hostname >, but how can i do this programmatically in objective-c? Thanks.

Comment: There is already a similar question - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572697/how-to-get-domain-name-of-ipaddress-and-ipaddress-from-domain-name-in-objective) (assuming you are using Mac OS).

Comment: can't you do a dns query?  Not sure about objective C, but I know the regular C equivalent is getHostByName.

Comment: that question shows how to find the name given an ip address.

Comment: im not sure how to, but tat might be the way to go. can you offer any more guidance?

Comment: you may find this question indirectly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145895/gethostbyname-xcode-issues  That said, I've never written a line of objective C, nor have I done any development on a mac or ios device.

Comment: yes. and it does it using `getaddrinfo`. I guess Lyubomir fancied you could try a `man getaddrinfo` before rejecting his suggestion.

Comment: ok, well, gethostbyname() for example works for website's ip addresses like "google.com," but it doesn't work for finding the ip address of a computer on your network like "bob's Mac" for instance. Is there an additional configuration that needs to be set up for this?

Comment: thanks Wug! getHostByName works, but it seems to only work for websites like "google.com." Is there any way I can make it work to find an ip address of a computer on the LAN? Like an additional configuration setting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, gethostbyname() always works when trying to find the ip address given a hostname, as long as the hostname of the computer you ae trying to access has its name registered in a DNS Server. All comments and answers above were useful.