# How to get the device name and type of device while scan local network?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am scanning my local network and i am getting their ip and their mac address, but i want also the device name like "Hassan's Iphone" and type of device, so help me how can i get this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to have a look at something like in the following link:

- [Stumbler](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/)

> We deal with anything wireless on the iPhone: 802.11, GSM, and Bluetooth. 
>   Stumbler lets you view the wireless networks in your area. While right now Stumbler only handles 802.11 networks, soon you should see Bluetooth and GSM capabilities as well. Stumbler is still in a early Alpha stage, but it is fully functional, and pretty stable

However they also  thoroughly mention that:

**Stumbler can not be distributed through the app store, as it uses private APIs!**

Following is the [link](http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/) to the blog post where I found the above Stumbler Google Code Project!

So I'm not sure even if what you require is possible to do, it won't be able to publish through the Apple App Store.

You better read the following StackOverflow answers too:

1. [Programmatically finding IP address of another computer on LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940341/programmatically-finding-ip-address-of-another-computer-on-lan)
2. [gethostbyname xcode issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145895/gethostbyname-xcode-issues)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27099363/1752988
4. [How Scan devices in a LAN network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953119/how-scan-devices-in-a-lan-network)
5. [Another blog post which mentioned about Stumbler tool](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/26/network-scanner-analysis-tool-ios-fing/)
6. [iOS. get other device/computer name by IP in the same local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376123/ios-get-other-device-computer-name-by-ip-in-the-same-local-network)
7. [iOS - How to get device make and model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model)
8. [LAN-Scan Git Hub Project](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan)

I think it's better next time before you put a StackOverflow Question please research on the web using Google and StackOverflow both together!

Comment: +1 for effort, @Randika thanks for your Answer and suggestion but still i didn't find answer of my question

Comment: Yes, I know that you might not find an answer out of mine, but after all it's a help to improve the background knowledge isn't it? Anyway as I think your question is deeply involved in the research of the iOS Platform and its given capabilities to the public developers!